# any public api which I can test jsonp ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Besides Twitter, I am wondering anyone knows any public web API whcih I can try ajax call with jsonp protocol?

Comment: Test how? Couldn't you just create a throwaway local jsonp service? In any case, jsfiddle has one.

Answer (score 10):

jsfiddle provides an echo facility which is quite useful: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

> JSONP URL: http://jsfiddle.net/echo/jsonp/
>
> Data has to be provided via GET. jsFiddle will respond all data given
>   in request. It uses URL with host and protocol as it’s loaded from
>   different domain. callback and delay will not be returned.
>
> callback name of the jsonp function delay optional, it’s a time in
>   seconds after which data should be returned